# How can I remove wapiti?

Tags: uninstall

I downloaded a tool called wapiti and I tried to install it manually and I did but then I removed it using sudo apt-get remove wapiti and also purge but every time I type wapiti it shows this:

```
salman@salman-EP31-DS3L:~$ wapiti
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/wapiti", line 9, in 
    load_entry_point('wapiti3==3.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'wapiti')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 542, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2569, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2229, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2235, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wapiti3-3.0.1-py2.7.egg/wapitiCore/main/wapiti.py", line 381
    print("{}: {}".format(exception.__class__.__name__, exception), file=fd)
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea??

Comment: What does `which wapiti` or `whereis wapiti` give you?

Comment: /usr/local/bin/wapiti

Comment: Run the second command so we know where all the files are if any!

Comment: wapiti: /usr/local/bin/wapit same output

Comment: Ok, now remove that file `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/wapiti`!

Comment: Great kindly accept my posted anwer below!

Comment: i got another problem .. i installed it using sudo apt-get install wapiti but then when i type wapiti nothing occurs and it gives me this bash: /usr/local/bin/wapiti

Comment: you installed or removed, which is it?

Comment: i installed it again but using this command sudo apt-get install wapiti .. the first installation was manual .. but it still doesnt work with me

Comment: What are the exact error messages seen!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/wapiti", line 36, in <module>
    from wapitiCore.language.language import Language
ImportError: cannot import name Language

Comment: Looks like a python error perhaps bug!

Comment: See: https://sourceforge.net/p/wapiti/discussion/575786/thread/b3427d10/, and https://sourceforge.net/p/wapiti/bugs/48/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find where the files associated with that program are with:

```
whereis wapiti
```

Then remove it with:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/wapiti
```